# How to put current timestamp in GraphQL mutation schema on server-side?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I need to put current timestamp in mutation query when user cancels the order.
It should be on server-side (cause it's not ok to rely on client's data).

Here is a simple mutation in my Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL schema:

```
type Mutation {
    cancelOrder(id: ID!, canceled_at: DateTime = "2021-02-19 12:00:00"): Order @update
}
```

How to change this hardcoded timestamp with some sort of *now()* function result? Like this:

```
cancelOrder(id: ID!, canceled_at: DateTime = current_timestamp): Order @update
```

Comment: You can use `@event` directive to execute Code after `@update` was successful: https://lighthouse-php.com/5.1/api-reference/directives.html#event
Alternatively you could probably write some kind of your own middleware-directive, it will be executed before `@update` resolver

Comment: @lorado Thank! I've written a custom mutator, but `@event` is also an option. I've just thought there should be some built in timestamp resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom mutation like `php artisan lighthouse:mutation Order`, then on my schema removed the `@update`  and the put the `@field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\Order@cancel")`, then on class Order do like:

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Mutations;

class Order
{
   /**
   * @param  null  $_
   * @param  array<string, mixed>  $args
   */
   public function cancel($_, array $args)
   {
       $order = Order::findOrFail($args['id']);
       $order->canceled_at = now();
       $order->save();

       return $order;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I've done the same way! Thank you for your answer! I've just thought there was a more laconic solution.